# When is the inverse image of a disk under a polynomial again a topological disk?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose $p(z)=z^2+c$ and $p^{\circ 5}$ is the first iterate $p^{\circ k}$ for which $p^{\circ k}(0)$ is not in the unit disk $\mathbb D$. Is it true that $p^{\circ (-4)}(\mathbb D)$ is homoeomorphic to $\mathbb D$?

This seems to be implied in something that I've read and I do not understand why. I do understand why the preimage of a disk that does not contain $0$ is a union of two disks, as it is an unramified covering. I do not know how to argue in the presence of critical values.

Comment: Does $p^{\circ (-4)}$ denote the $"-4th"$ iteration of the map $p$?

Comment: Yes. The inverse image of the fourth iterate.

Comment: Actually I am not sure but I believe that Gamelin and Carlsson's complex dynamics book is a good reference if you know that? Where did you encounter this issue.